# socket io not emit event to all users in room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

I am working on a chat using io socket using rooms.
The problem I have is that when I add two users, the one who initiates the chat and a receptor user, when issuing an event does not reach the sender of the same.
I found that if I used the .in method, I could send the event to everyone inside the room, but it still only reaches the receiver and never the one who started the chat.
I am using this code:

```
socket.join(conversation.id, () =>
      console.log(`Buyer ${buyerProfile.id} joined to room`)
    );
    socket
      .to(bidderProfile.socketId)
      .join(conversation.id, () =>
        console.log(`Bidder ${bidderProfile.id} joined to room`)
      );
    socket.in(conversation.id).emit(CONVERSATION_READY, conversation);
```

Comment: `.join()` is asynchronous.  Trying sending the message in the `.join()` callback after you know it's complete.

Comment: i try join the second user in the callback, and sending the message in the second callback but it still not working, only send the message to the second user.

Comment: You need to know when both callbacks are done.